# Pandas/Python group object of the same name and mean them

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have been struggling with this problem for hours now and cant seem to find a solution so Im hoping somobody can help me.

Im looking to find a mean response time for each ambulance base in my city. I have reduced the dataframe to "Station" and "Response Time" Im trying to now find the mean response time for each station. Here is first 4 values of my dataframe.

```
Station       Response
Tara Street       4
Finglas           6
Tara Street       7
Central           3
Tara Street       4
```

Now what im looking to do is calculate the mean response time of each station and sort them by said time. So it would look like this

```
Station        Response

Finglas            6 
Tara Street        5
Central            3
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Show us the code and what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html):

```
#first try cast to int, if error, try to_numeric
df.Response = df.Response.astype(int)

#castvalues to int or floats, if some non numeric replace them by NaN 
#df.Response = pd.to_numeric(df.Response, errors='coerce')

df = df.groupby('Station')['Response'].mean().sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index()
print (df)
       Station  Response
0      Finglas         6
1  Tara Street         5
2      Central         3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried it and i get the following error

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

I tried 
    df["Response"].apply(int)
and it returns:

   'Name: Response, dtype: int64'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` for aggregating catgories

```
df.groupby('Station').mean().sort_values('Response', ascending=False)
```